# Assign a function to a new variable

Tags: c++

Why can't I assign my `new_age(age)` to another variable (in this case it will be `new`)?

I get the following errors:

```
main.cpp:21:9: error: expected type-specifier before ‘=’ token
   21 |     new = new_age(age)
      |         ^
```

---

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int new_age (int & age)
{
    return (age + 100);
}

int main()
{
    int age {};
    new = new_age(age)
    
    cout << "How old are you "
    cin >> age
    cout << "In 100 years you will be " << new:

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new` is a keyword; you can’t assign a value to it.

Comment: You also have a lot of typoes in there (missing `;` in particular). And code is executed top to bottom in a function, you can't calculate new age before getting a value for age from the user.

Comment: Also even if you could name a variable `new`, the syntax to do would be `int new = new_age(age);` because you'd have to specify the type of the variable.

Comment: When I do int not_new = new_age(gap) and then do cout << not_new it will print out "100" not "100 + age" (age is the number that the user inputed.

Answer (score 1):

The word `new` is a keyword in C++. It has a special meaning and cannot be used as name of a variable.

For a full list of all keywords see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword).

As an aside, even if `new` was allowed as an identifier, you have not declared it. To declare and initialize it directly with the value you need to add the variable's type in front of the identifier:

```
int not_new = new_age(age);
```

(Also note the semicolon at the end of the declaration which you forgot or mistyped in a lot of statements as well.)

It also seems that you'd want to call `new_age(age)` *after* taking input from the user.

Comment: When I do int not_new = new_age(gap) and then do cout << not_new it will print out "100" not "100 + age" (age is the number that the user inputed.

Comment: @Cidrant See the last sentence in my answer and also the other comments under your question. The function body is executed from top to bottom. So you need to make sure that you call your function _after_ you take the input from the user.